# Poco ODBC MS SQL: temp tables

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc, poco-libraries

I want to create temp tables and use it later in one session. I can create it, but then when I try to use to I receive:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name #my_table

I try the same queries in SSMS and everything works correctly.

For example

```cpp
...
std::shared_ptr<Poco::Data::Session> session;
...
Poco::Data::Statement createStatement(*session);
createStatement<< create_temp_table_and_insert_into_temp_table;
createStatement.execute();

Poco::Data::Statement insertStatement(*session);
insertStatement<< select_from_temp_table;
insertStatement.execute(); <- exception Invalid object name
```

Another example

```cpp
...
std::shared_ptr<Poco::Data::Session> session;
...
*session.get() << "IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#test') is not null) drop table #test;";
*session.get() << "create table #test (s1 int,s2 int ,s3 int);";
*session.get() << "insert into #test select 1,2,3";
typedef Poco::Tuple<int, int, int> testParam;
std::vector<testParam> testParams;
*session.get() << QString("select * from #test").toStdString(), Poco::Data::Keywords::into(testParams),
            Poco::Data::Keywords::now;
```

I tried the same with qt odbc driver and queries also work. I also tried Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server} and old driver DRIVER={SQL Server} too.

Comment: In Microsoft SQL Server those `#temp` tables are connection-specific. If your Session object is `close()`d and re-`open()`ed, or if you call `reconnect()` anywhere, that Session object will have a different database connection and the `#temp` table will no longer exist.

Comment: I don't reopen or reconnect. I also cannot use ##temp tables. But if i create ##temp table in ms sms, then I can access it from Poco (if ms sms session still exists)

Comment: Yes, because `##temp` tables are "global" temp tables that can, locks permitting, be shared between connections. Global temp tables can hang around until the last reference is released.

Comment: Perhaps the better question is why you think local temp tables are useful for your actual goal. Often I see the pattern of "select .. into x ; select from x" for no particular reason - that pattern serves no useful purpose in many cases.

Comment: If I create ##temp global in Poco, I cannot access it in Poco.

Comment: @SMor it's useful because it actually uses in production but not with poco.

Comment: Are you parameterizing the creata-and-insert statement? You must put `CREATE TABLE #temp` separately in a **non-parameterized** statement, because otherwise it gets called with `sp_executesql` which executes under a different context

Comment: @Charlieface i tried ```select  into #temp``` in one statement and then ```select  from #temp``` without explicit ```create table```

Comment: I also tried: ```session << "drop table #temp;";```
  ```session << "create table #temp...";```
  ```session << insert_into_#temp;``` Then ```Poco::Data::Statement statement(*session);
  statement << select_from_#temp
  statement.execute(); <- exception```